# Changing MultiIndex Headers List to Array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I'm looking to query information based on multiple header criteria. When reading the file with 6 header rows, it looks like the headers are being read as 1 large list rather than 6 arrays. In order to use multiindex functions, do I need to convert to arrays? How is this done?

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header = [0,1,2,3,4,5], index_col = 0)
list(data)

[('US Banks', 'Main', 'Sectors', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'Modified Duration'),
 ('US Banks', 'Main', 'Sectors', 'ALL', '1-3', 'Modified Duration'),
 ('US Banks', 'Main', 'Sectors', 'ALL', '3-5', 'Modified Duration'),
 ('US Banks', 'Main', 'Sectors', 'ALL', '5-7', 'Modified Duration'),
 ('US Banks', 'Main', 'Sectors', 'ALL', '7-10', 'Modified Duration'),
 ('US Banks', 'Main', 'Sectors', 'ALL', '10+', 'Modified Duration'),...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples`

```
data.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(data))
```